# When Email input field is alerted, would not go to next input field Dotnet Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller

[test@123.com mail id is stored in database previously](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AogVc.png)

[image: When new user use same email id it throws an error. I want to make when error thrown, user cannot go to next input field]

```
public void AddStudent(Student student)
        {
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                SqlCommand cmdCheckEmail = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Student WHERE Email = @Email", con);
                cmdCheckEmail.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", student.Email);

                SqlCommand cmdAddStudent = new SqlCommand("spAddStudent", con);
                cmdAddStudent.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmdAddStudent.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", student.FirstName);
                cmdAddStudent.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", student.LastName);
                cmdAddStudent.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", student.Email);
                cmdAddStudent.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mobile", student.Mobile);
                cmdAddStudent.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", student.Address);

                con.Open();

                int emailCount = (int)cmdCheckEmail.ExecuteScalar();

                if (emailCount > 0)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Email already exists in the database.");
                }

                cmdAddStudent.ExecuteNonQuery();

                con.Close();
            }
        }
```

I write code for duplicating Email IDs in the SQL server database. When the user enters the same Mail id it throws an error and I want to make it cannot go to the next input field i.e. Mobile input field.

Comment: Don't use `AddWithValue`: https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I suggest you could consider using the remote  validation for that Email attribute.

By using the remote validation you could add a new method inside the controller and add the remote attribute for that Email property, then inside the client, you should enable the client-side validation, jquery-validation-unobtrusive. When the user type-in Email, the client will call the remote method to check the Email and directly return true or false to not let the user continue editing other input.

More details, you could refer to below codes:

Inside controller add below method:

```
[AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST")]
public IActionResult VerifyEmail(string email)
{
    if (!_userService.VerifyEmail(email))
    {
        return Json($"Email {email} is already in use.");
    }

    return Json(true);
}
```

Inside your model, use it like below:

```
[Remote(action: "VerifyEmail", controller: "Users")]
public string Email { get; set; } = null!;
```

Inside view, please enable the jquery-validation-unobtrusive.

```
@section Scripts {  
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}  
}
```